# How to use different ChangeTracker instances for each inMemory Database?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, in-memory-database

I'm trying to use InMemory Database to help test out my methods.

I'm having trouble running multiple DataRows in a test because all but one will give me an error when trying to add a default record to the context. If I manually run each individually they all pass but as soon as I run the whole test they fail when all but one reach `mCntx.Brokers.Add(new() ...` with the following error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Broker' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'
```

I've tried setting up a new Db name as is recommended but it still seems to draw from the same ChangeTracker.

*Test Code*

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [DataRow(null, _ValidBrokerNameNotInDb, _ValidBrokerageIdInDb, _ValidBrokerageNameInDb)]
    [DataRow(null, _ValidBrokerNameNotInDb, null, _ValidBrokerageNameInDb)]
    [DataRow(null, _ValidBrokerNameNotInDb, _ValidBrokerageIdInDb, null)]
    [DataRow(null, _ValidBrokerNameNotInDb, null, _ValidBrokerageNameNotInDb)]
    public void BrokerValidationTest_CreateInDb(int? brokerId, string brokerName, int? brokerageId, string brokerageName)
    {

        DataTable dataTable = GetDataTable(brokerId, brokerName, brokerageId, brokerageName);
        List<UploadIssue> uploadIssues = new();
        var rand = new Random().NextDouble();
        using (SqlDboDbContext cntx = GetContext($"BrokerValidationTest_CreateInDb{rand}"))
        {
            InsertUpdateDatabaseService.ImportBroker(dataTable, cntx, ref uploadIssues);
            cntx.ChangeTracker.Clear();
        }

        Assert.IsFalse(uploadIssues.Any(x => x.UploadIssueType == UploadIssueTypes.Error));
        Assert.IsFalse(uploadIssues.Any(x => x.UploadIssueType == UploadIssueTypes.DependencyError));
        Assert.IsFalse(uploadIssues.Any(x => x.UploadIssueType == UploadIssueTypes.Prompt));
    }

    public static SqlDboDbContext GetContext(string dbName)
    {
        var rand = new Random().NextDouble();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SqlDboDbContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: dbName + rand.ToString())
            .Options;

        SqlDboDbContext mCntx = new SqlDboDbContext(options);
        mCntx.Brokers.Add(new()
        {
            Id = _ValidBrokerIdInDb,
            Name = _ValidBrokerNameInDb,
            BrokerageId = _ValidBrokerageIdInDb,
            Brokerage = DbBrokerage
        });
        mCntx.SaveChanges();
        return mCntx;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue it seems to be with `Brokerage = DbBrokerage`

```
    private static Brokerage DbBrokerage = new()
    {
        Id = _ValidBrokerageIdInDb,
        Name = _ValidBrokerageNameInDb
    };
```

Once I changed it to creating a new instance of Brokerage instead of using the static instance it started working.

From

```
    mCntx.Brokers.Add(new()
    {
        Id = _ValidBrokerIdInDb,
        Name = _ValidBrokerNameInDb,
        BrokerageId = _ValidBrokerageIdInDb,
        Brokerage = DbBrokerage
    });
```

To

```
    mCntx.Brokers.Add(new()
    {
        Id = _ValidBrokerIdInDb,
        Name = _ValidBrokerNameInDb,
        BrokerageId = _ValidBrokerageIdInDb,
        Brokerage = new()
        {
            Id = _ValidBrokerageIdInDb,
            Name = _ValidBrokerageNameInDb
        }
    });
```